# How to use XML node Extracted Value using xpath as a File name in Azure Logic App

Tags: xml, azure, xpath, azure-logic-apps

I want to set my folder name to a value that I extracted from an HTTP request using XPath.

I am trying this expression as folder name:

```
 /@xpath(xml(triggerBody()), '//*[local-name()='MyNodeName']/text()')
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Which connector action r u using for "create File"? Try using compose action to see what is the xpath value returned